# How do I select a value from a combo box to display an associated value in c#

Tags: c#, combobox, ms-access-2010

I have a combo box within a WinForm using C# that displays a list of customer names from an MS Access Database. I have another textbox where I want to display the customer ID on the selection of the customer name using the combo box? The code I have used to display the list of names in the combo box is as follows;

```
public void homeFrm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Carmine_Cycle_Couriers_Database.accdb");
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT CustomerID, FirstName from tblCustomer", cn);
        DataSet dt = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(dt, "FirstName");
        cboCustomerSelect.DataSource = dt.Tables["FirstName"];
        cboCustomerSelect.DisplayMember = "FirstName";
        cboCustomerSelect.ValueMember = "CustomerID";
        cboCustomerSelect.Text = "Select Customer";
    }
```

Comment: You didn't ask a (real) question. -- Btw, the Connection is disposable, the DataAdapter and the DataSet are wasted here, just load a DataTable using a DataReader, `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` should be set before the `DataSource` -- You should probably bind the TextBox's `Text` Property to the same data source (to the `CustomerID` Column)

Comment: Hi Jimi, thanks for your response. My question is, when I run the program, and select the customer name from the combo box drop down list, how do I get the other text box to display the associated Customer ID? I hope that makes sense,

Comment: I've already mentioned it: bind the `Text` Property of that TextBox to the same data source (the DataTable). The Binding is set to the `CustomerID` Column of you DataTable (see. [Control.DataBindings.Add()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.databindings))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Value` property of cboCustomerSelect to get the CustomerId. You can use combobox `selectedindexchanged` event and do the following

```
yourTextBox.Text = cboCustomerSelect.Value.ToString();
```